# How to build this screen in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development and am trying to build something like the screen below:

[image: The screen I'm trying to build]

If I was doing it in Android, I can easily build the above UI in a few minutes. However, I don't know how to go about it with iOS.

I understand that the whole `ViewController` can be embedded in a navigation controller, which produces the title bar above. What about the bottom part though? I'm thinking of using something like a grouped `UITableView` but I'm not sure, since every cell will have very different contents:

1. A search bar, perhaps a subclassed `UISearchBar`, which I also don't know how to customize--the Search button at the right is required but isn't in the default `UISearchBar`. When the user taps on it, the `UISearchBar` must be translated to the navigation bar, no need to display a `UITableView` of suggested results. I don't know how to do that, too.
2. A button that, when tapped, flies in a modal from the bottom (I imagine it to be another `ViewController` with a grouped `UITableView`), to allow the user to choose from defined locations. Once selected, the modal closes and the button text is replaced with the selected location. This sounds much easier to do.
3. A header ("Item categories") and the list of categories, which may change in number. If the parent isn't a grouped `UITableView`, I think this part can be a `UILabel` and a non-scrolling `UITableView` with a height that changes depending on how many cells it has. If there are plenty table cells that don't fit given the screen's height, everything below the navigation bar can be scrolled vertically. That, I also don't know how to do.

If anyone can just guide me to what native iOS components I can use to build the above screen, and maybe a couple of tutorials to the things I just said I don't know how to do, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If all the content of the view will be scrollable, then a tableView is probably the right way to go about it. You'd probably want to have different sections for the 1,2 & 3 pieces above and simply use different cellTypes for the three different content-types.

Comment: I think you really need to do a few iOS development tutorials to get a better idea of how an app hangs together. You seem to have roughly the right idea but your questions are really too broad to attempt to answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it right .All the basic info you need is with you.

- To build a searchbar like that i dont think you have to subclass it.
- Bottom comprises of tableview.

Actually these Questions are seperately available in SO itself.So search seperately for your needs and you can achieve whatever you want

One basic principle : You cant achive anything by just thinking.Trying and get to it and if you have any issues look forward at it.All the issues will have an answer on the way.

Comment: What about the parent of the three components? Should I make it a scroll view or a grouped table view?

Comment: scrollview or tableview? Why a scrollview is needed? Inside a viewcontroller objecta add all components and you are good to go.Adding tableview on sccrollview will cause trouble on tableview scroll .apple says not to do so

Comment: Use a navigation view for the title, holding a table view for everything else.  The 3 sections are table view sections and create cells to hold all the different types of widgets.  I would suggest going through a good UITableView tutorial as that knowledge is fundamental in creating this.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of components you need there.. Search Bar, UIPickerView and UITableView. I would like to give you some pointers.

1) You can refer http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/ for Search bar

2) When clicking on the Button, you can bring up a UIPickerView instead of another controller. For that you can refer http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example

3) You can use a normal Tableview with a single section, configure the section header to display Item categories.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too much to ask how to do every component of your UI. I will just answer a little.

Yes, a grouped table view is a good design. I am using a grouped table view for varying types of input. I have an actual table, with rows that can be added, and deleted, and contain an editable text area. Then I have three groups that only really show one piece of content each: two are sliders and one is a switch.

For choosing the location, pushing another view controller on your navigation stack would be the more typical way to handle it. You will save some effort that way, with some buttons and behaviors built in, but a modal view controller is not much harder. I'm not sure if you can make a navigation view fly in vertically, but does your app have to be frame-for-frame identical to the android version?

Comment: No, in fact the Android version doesn't do that--I came up with the idea by observing other iOS apps, specifically Google Search. Thanks for the tip, will try this out.